# MergePDF Field empty while merging with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am using PDFMerge PDF lib for multiple pdf merge but if PDF is Editable like Form fields in PDF then it will make empty fields with merging.

i am using latest code

Please help me

Comment: show your attempt.

Comment: I guess the script uses FPDI in the back, which is simply not able to handle dynamic content outside of a content stream. See [here](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-85).